# SSL Handshake Error while calling Visual Recognition in Watson

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-watson, java-6, watson

I am getting SSL Handshake error while trying to call Watson Visual Recognition Service through java. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException    {
   VisualRecognition service = new VisualRecognition(VisualRecognition.VERSION_DATE_2016_05_20);
   service.setApiKey("api_key");

   InputStream imagesStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\fruitbowl.jpg");
   ClassifyOptions classifyOptions =
           new ClassifyOptions.Builder().imagesFile(imagesStream).imagesFilename("fruitbowl.jpg")
                   .parameters(
                           "{\"classifier_ids\": [\"fruits_1462128776\", + \"SatelliteModel_6242312846\"],\"threshold\": 0.6}")
                   .build();
   ClassifiedImages result = service.classify(classifyOptions).execute();
   System.out.println(result);
    }}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
>      at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService$1.execute(WatsonService.java:176)
>      at editcsvfile.csv.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:22)
>   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Comment: Are you using IBM JDK ? If so, please edit your question. If you can tell us which version too, it's nice.

Comment: I am getting a different error now.

Comment: have you managed to resolve this? I am getting the same problem with IBM Watson assistant